# Jenkins just login at the second attempt

Tags: authentication, jenkins

When I do a deploy on jenkins it fails at the first attempt, but second attempt suceeds.

The same for the (web console) login. When I try to login in first time it fails, but when I retry the login suceeds. (Yes, I typed my password correctly both times).

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.teste:test:jar:0.8.0 from/to artifactory.test.com(http://artifactory.test/libs-release-local): Failed to transfer file: http://artifactory.test.com/libs-release-local/com/test/test/0.8.0/test-0.8.0.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase:Bad credentials. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix  `<ldapUrl>` tag in /app/artifactory/etc/artifactory.config.latest.xml file